# How do I get the root directory of an S3 bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I specify the prefix as an empty string or null, it will not query back the root documents.

```
new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName).withPrefix(prefix);
```

EDIT:

It would be interesting to know if there's a way to query back only folders that are 1 directory above.

Answer (score 0):

```
new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName).withDelimiter("/");
```

They end with / as a delimeter so ^ worked..